# Need to find the class paths' urls from inside a maven plugin

Tags: maven-plugin

I am working on a mojo that eventually will connect to a background process.

The mojo needs to pass this process the uri/urls of the dependencies.

I tried Dependency.getSystemPath().

It returns null and it is discouraged.

Could anybody point to a place where I can find these urXs?

I am using maven-xxx-2.2.1.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: From what I can understand an ArtifactRepository should be able to return the path to an artifact. I can get the dependency artifacts from the project. But I can't seem to find a way to get the local artifact repo.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively safe assumption is that the local repo is under ~/.m2. With this and the artifact id one should be able to create a uri/url for the local artifacts.

That is in the case that one has not been able to find an instance of LocalArtifactRepository.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the very limited documentation on Maven Mojo development, you would want to work with a project's **artifacts** rather than - as you suggest - its **dependencies**.

A `Dependency` is simply the configuration of that in the POM, meaning `Dependency` is a pretty dumb object that knows little more than what is in the POM in the `<dependencies>` section.

What you really want is `Artifact` which in Maven terminology terms is both what the project produces but also what it consumes. When talking about the consumption side I tend to think of an artifact as a 'resolved dependency'.

To get the project's dependencies (as artifacts) I use either one of the below statements:

```java
Set<Artifact> deps = project.getDependencyArtifacts(); // gets direct deps
Set<Artifact> deps = project.getArtifacts();  // gets all deps, incl transitive ones
```

Now, the beauty is that the Artifact has a method called `getFile()` which gives you exactly what you want (you just need to convert that into an URL). There's also a `getDownloadUrl()` method but I'm assuming that it will return NULL if Maven didn't have to download anything, i.e. if the artifact was found in the local repo.

You may get NULL returned from `getFile()` if you are at a phase where Maven has yet not resolved and downloaded dependencies. In other words: the Artifact object is lazily loaded with content.